# Returning value on Async DB query

Tags: java, database, asynchronous, hikaricp

I'm looking for an all-purpose method to return a ResultSet (or a CachedResultSet, since the connection closes) from a HikariCP database query

I looked around and one suggested option was using FutureTask with a Callback, this is what I tried:

```
    public static CachedRowSet query(String query) {
    FutureTask<CachedRowSet> future =
            new FutureTask(new Callable() {
                public CachedRowSet call() {
                    try {
                        Connection connection = hikari.getConnection();
                        ResultSet set = connection.prepareStatement(query).executeQuery();

                        CachedRowSet crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
                        crs.populate(set);

                        set.close();
                        connection.close();

                        return crs;
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();;
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            });

    try {
        CachedRowSet crs = future.get();
        return crs;
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

It just hangs. The method as a whole doesn't complete, I'm wondering what I did wrong? (Querying the database regularly is no issue as I moved to this just a moment ago)

Alternatively, would you be able to kindly suggest a better option and guide me on my way?

Comment: That's not an async method. It's a method containing (kind of) async code, then it calls `future.get()` waiting for results, i.e. blocking execution.

Comment: Oh- right! I had assumed that the Callback would execute in async, I was mistaken. Even so, if this doesn't work in sync it definitely won't work async!